# How does newCachedThreadPool reuse threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, executorservice, threadpoolexecutor

I want to ask for a little more detail to the same question posted by Zeller over a year ago...

*The javadoc says that the service returned by `Executors.newCachedThreadPool` reuses threads. How is this possible?*

I get how the queue structure is setup internally, what I don't see is how it reuses threads in the queue.

All examples I've seen have the developer create an instance of their thread and pass it in through the "execute" method.

For example...

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {            
  Runnable worker = new WorkerThread(i);  //will create 10 instances          
  executor.execute(worker);          
}
```

I understand that a thread pool can easily manage the life cycle of each thread, but again, I see no methods nor the ability to access or restart any of the threads in the pool.

In the above example, I would then expect that each thread would be started, run, terminated and disposed of by the thread pool, but never reused.

A messaging system would be an example of where you'd need this.  Say you have an onMessage handler and you'd like to reuse one of the threads in the pool to handle it, so I'd expect methods like...

```
worker = executor.getIdleThread;
worker.setData(message);
executor.resubmit(worker);
```

or maybe have the ExecutorService acting as a factory class and have it return an instance of your threads, where internally it decides to create a new one or reuse an old one.

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool(WorkerThread);
Runnable worker = executor.getThread;
worker.setData(message);
```

So I'm missing something.  It's probably something simple but I've spent the afternoon reading tutorials and examples and still haven't figured it out.  Can someone shed some light on the subject?

Comment: Why don't you look at the source code?

Comment: Or better, the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html), where you'll see that `ExecutorService.execute()` does *not* take a `Thread` as its argument. Any example that passes an actual thread to this method should be ignored as written by someone who doesn't know what he/she is doing.

Comment: @kdgregory Technically, a `Thread` is a `Runnable` and so is a valid argument. It depends how it is used.

Comment: I'll repeat: someone who creates a `Thread` to pass to a method that takes `Runnable` doesn't know what he/she is doing.

Comment: If all examples you've seen have the developer create an instance of `Thread` and pass it to the `execute` method you either haven’t seen much examples yet or are in a very bad luck. Well, we may blame Sun for that design mistake of letting `Thread` implement `Runnable` and expose that `run()` method that never ought to be invoked…

Answer (score 3):

I was curious too how this was possible since Threads can't be restarted, so I analyzed the code of `ThreadPoolExecutor` which is the implementation of all the ThreadPool `ExecutorService` you get through the static constructor.

First of all as stated in the other answer you don't use Threads, but Runnables in ThreadPools, because that would defeat the purpose. So here is a detailed explaination how an ExecutorService reuses Threads:

You usually add a Runnable through `submit()` which internally calls the `execute()` method. Basically this adds the runnable to a queue and adds a Worker if none is working ATM

```
public void execute(Runnable command) {
        ...
        int c = ctl.get();
        if (workerCountOf(c) < corePoolSize) {
            if (addWorker(command, true))
                return;
            c = ctl.get();
        }
        if (isRunning(c) && workQueue.offer(command)) {
            int recheck = ctl.get();
            if (! isRunning(recheck) && remove(command))
                reject(command);
            else if (workerCountOf(recheck) == 0)
                addWorker(null, false);
        }
        else if (!addWorker(command, false))
            reje
ct(command);
    }
```

The executor maintains a bunch of Worker (inner Class of `ThreadPoolExecutor`). It has your submitted runnable and a Thread that will be created through the ThreadFactory you maybe set or else just a default one; also the Worker itself is a Runnable, which is used to create the Thread from the factory

```
private final class Worker
        extends AbstractQueuedSynchronizer
        implements Runnable
    {
...
   Worker(Runnable firstTask) {
     this.firstTask = firstTask;
     this.thread = getThreadFactory().newThread(this);
   }

   public void run() {
      runWorker(this);
   }
...
}
```

When adding a Worker it gets kickstarted

```
private boolean addWorker(Runnable firstTask, boolean core) {
    ...
    Worker w = new Worker(firstTask);
    Thread t = w.thread;
    ...
    t.start();
    ...
    return true;
}
```

the `runWorker()` method runs in a loop and get with `getTask()` the runnables you submitted which are queued in the `workingQueue` and will wait at getTask unitl a timeout happens.

```
   final void runWorker(Worker w) {
        Runnable task = w.firstTask;
        w.firstTask = null;
        boolean completedAbruptly = true;
        try {
            while (task != null || (task = getTask()) != null) {
                w.lock();
                clearInterruptsForTaskRun();
                try {
                    beforeExecute(w.thread, task);
                    Throwable thrown = null;
                    try {
                        task.run();
                    } catch (RuntimeException x) {
                    ...
                    } finally {
                        afterExecute(task, thrown);
                    }
                } finally {
                    task = null;
                    w.completedTasks++;
                    w.unlock();
                }
            }
            completedAbruptly = false;
        } finally {
            processWorkerExit(w, completedAbruptly);
        }
    }
```

Here is the getTask() method

```
private Runnable getTask() {
   ...
        try {
            Runnable r = timed ?
                workQueue.poll(keepAliveTime, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS) :
                workQueue.take();
            ..
        } catch (InterruptedException retry) {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

---

**tl;dr** So basically the Threadpool maintains worker threads that run in loops and execute runnables given by a blocking queue. The worker will be created and destroyed due to demand (no more tasks, a worker will end; if no free worker and < maxPoolSize then create new worker). Also I wouldn't call it "reuse" more the thread will be used as a looper to execute all runnables.

Answer (score 2):

> I understand that a **thread pool can** easily **manage** the life cycle of
>   each thread, but again, I see no methods nor the ability to access or
>   restart any of the threads in the pool.

The management of threads is done internally. The `ExecutorService` interface only provides the externally visible methods.

The [javadoc of `newCachedThreadPool`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newCachedThreadPool%28%29) simply states

> Creates a thread pool that creates new threads as needed, but will
>   reuse previously constructed threads when they are available. [...] **Calls to execute will reuse
>   previously constructed threads if available.** If no existing thread is
>   available, a new thread will be created and added to the pool. Threads
>   that have not been used for sixty seconds are terminated and removed
>   from the cache. Thus, a pool that remains idle for long enough will
>   not consume any resources. [...]

So that is the guarantee you get. If you want to know how it is implemented, you can look at the source code, in particular, the code of `ThreadPoolExecutor`. Basically, idle threads will terminate after not executing a task after some time.